# Currency converter in php :only one side convertion is worked

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am trying to implement currency convertion in my web page.

Here is the work flow

1.User can select the currency from drop down menu.

2.According to this prizes listed in the page is changed with respect to newly selected currency.

**Code**

1.When a user select an item from dropdown menu currency value set in a session variable  and the page is reloaded using `ajax` call .

```
<select id="curr-dropmenu">
    <option disabled="" selected="">Choose</option>
<option value="INR">INR</option>
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="AED">AED</option>
<option value="FED">FED</option>
<option value="XBJ">XBJ</option>
</select>
```

ajax call

```
$('#curr-dropmenu').on('change',function(e){
       //ajax call for setting the currency in session
       $.ajax({
           url:'ajax_set.php',
           data:{currency:$(this).val()},
           method:"POST",
           success:function(data){

               location.reload();
           },
           error:function(data){

               alert("ERROR"+JSON.strinfy(data));
           }
       });
    });
```

In `ajax_set.php` file

```
<?php
session_start();  
$_SESSION['old_currency']= (!empty($_SESSION['new_currency']))?$_SESSION['new_currency']:'INR';
$_SESSION['new_currency']=$_POST['currency'];
```

2.When the page is reloaded get the previous and current currency are fetched from the session and make an api request to `google currency converter` to convert the amount to the selected prize.

```
    <?php
     //getting the currency values from session.
         session_start();
       //old currency
         $from=(!empty($_SESSION['old_currency']))?$_SESSION['old_currency']:'INR';
         echo 'From:&nbsp;'.$from.'<br>';
  //new currency  
  $to=(!empty($_SESSION['new_currency']))?$_SESSION['new_currency']:'INR';
         echo 'To:&nbsp;'.$to.'<br>';
    //amount to be converted.

    $prize=array('2000','600','7000','2500','100000');
    echo '<br><br>';
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        //call the currency convert function 
        if($from!=$to)
        {
            $response=currencyConvert($from,$to,$prize[$i]);
            $converted_amount=filter_var($response,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
        }
        else
        {
            $converted_amount=$prize[$i];
        }
        echo '<span>'.$converted_amount.' '.$to.'</span><hr/>';
    }


//make the api request for convert currency.
function currencyConvert($from,$to,$amount){
  // echo '<br>convert'.$f.'to'.$t;
    $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to"; 

    $request = curl_init(); 
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $regex  = '#\<span class=bld\>(.+?)\<\/span\>#s';
    preg_match($regex, $response, $converted);
    if(!empty($converted))
    return  ($converted[0])?$converted[0]:0;

}
```

This will works only in one way 
eg: if i convert INR to USD the conversion is correct,but when i select USD to INR it will get the wrong output.

Comment: I checked with `echo currencyConvert('USD', 'INR', 1.0200);` it showing correct result, same as https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1.0200&from=USD&to=INR

Answer (score 0):

Hi can it be that you send the same currency to the google service?

Change your check from

```
if ($from == $to)
```

to

```
if (strtoupper($from) == strtoupper($to))
```

Comment: the only problem what can be is if you send from INR (upper case) and to inr (lower case) then your check `if($from!=$to)` is not matching and you get from google back this message Could not convert.

Answer (score 0):

HI you need to change in php script to send converted prizes to google converter
try the following code and check

```
     //getting the currency values from session.
         session_start();
       //old currency
         $from=(!empty($_SESSION['old_currency']))?$_SESSION['old_currency']:'INR';
         echo 'From:&nbsp;'.$from.'<br>';
  //new currency  
  $to=(!empty($_SESSION['new_currency']))?$_SESSION['new_currency']:'INR';
         echo 'To:&nbsp;'.$to.'<br>';
    //amount to be converted.

    $prize=array('2000','600','7000','2500','100000');
 $prize_old =(!empty($_SESSION['old_prize']))?$_SESSION['old_prize']:$prize; 
$prize_new =(!empty($_SESSION['new_prize']))?$_SESSION['new_prize']:$prize;  
$prize_converted = array();
    echo '<br><br>';
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        //call the currency convert function 
        if($from!=$to)
        {
            $response=currencyConvert($from,$to, $prize_new[$i]);
            $converted_amount=filter_var($response,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
            array_push($prize_converted,round($converted_amount));
        }
        else
        {
            $converted_amount=$prize[$i];
             array_push($prize_converted,$converted_amount);

        }
        echo '<span>'.$converted_amount.' '.$to.'</span><hr/>';
    }
$_SESSION['old_priz'] = $prize;  
$_SESSION['new_prize'] = $prize_converted;


//make the api request for convert currency.
function currencyConvert($from,$to,$amount){
  // echo '<br>convert'.$f.'to'.$t;
     $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to"; 

    $request = curl_init(); 
    $timeOut = 0;
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
    curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $regex  = '#\<span class=bld\>(.+?)\<\/span\>#s';
    preg_match($regex, $response, $converted);
    if(!empty($converted))
    return  ($converted[0])?$converted[0]:0;

}
```

I hope this help